Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty
I'm trying to plot these following data:
0.000000000000E+0 1.973601225684E+0
1.000000000000E+0 1.973601176100E+0
2.000000000000E+0 1.973601185980E+0
3.000000000000E+0 1.973601205420E+0
4.000000000000E+0 1.973601263091E+0
5.000000000000E+0 1.973601194220E+0
6.000000000000E+0 1.973601106796E+0
7.000000000000E+0 1.973601142445E+0

To give some context, it's a voltage measurement with respect to time.
I've tried to plot it with tikz, by using \addplot coordinates but ended with Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty. By digging the web, I understood that my data as too much "significant digits" for Tikz but can be plotted with Gnuplot.
Indeed, the command gnuplot> plot 'X:\bw\mesures_h\rapports\z.dat' gives me:

At this point I try to plot in my LaTeX document using Gnuplot in TikZ, with the following MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{data.dat}
0.000000000000E+0 1.973601225684E+0
1.000000000000E+0 1.973601176100E+0
2.000000000000E+0 1.973601185980E+0
3.000000000000E+0 1.973601205420E+0
4.000000000000E+0 1.973601263091E+0
5.000000000000E+0 1.973601194220E+0
6.000000000000E+0 1.973601106796E+0
7.000000000000E+0 1.973601142445E+0
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot gnuplot [
            raw gnuplot,
        ] {
            plot 'data.dat' using 1:2;
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Unfortunately, after the same warning Package pgfplots Warning: Axis range for axis y is approximately empty, I get the following result:

Any idea or clue would be helpful. Thank in advance.
